# js - while loop only repeating once

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, fivem

I am learning to code.

I made the following script, where if executed will turn raveMode on or off depending on it's current state. My goal was to make it so that when raveMode was on it repeated a while loop until it was turned off again, however, it seems to work only partially.
Here is the code:

```
Delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    

raveMode = !raveMode
    print(raveMode)
    while (raveMode) {
      SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 2);
      await Delay(300);
      SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 0);
    }
```

Basically, the `SetVehicleLights(..., 2)` turns the vehicle lights on and `SetVehicleLighs(..., 0)` turns them off. However, the code only turns the lights on when raveMode is on and turns them off when raveMode is off, instead of repeateadly turning them on and off.

I use the same script in the code below and the lights are turned on and off once, as supposed in this case:

```
if (!GetIsVehicleEngineRunning(playerInfo.vehicle)) {
      SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 2);
      await Delay(300);
      SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 0);
}
```

Comment: If ravemode is true I would expect the lights to come on, a 300 delay, the lights to shut off for an instant or perhaps not visibly at all, and then the lights come on again.  So it would look like the lights are just on.

Comment: Thank you, @James, you were right. I added a new Delay after the lights are turned off.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is repeating just fine.  But there's *zero delay* between "turning the lights off" at the end of one iteration of the loop and "turning the lights on" at the beginning of the next iteration of the loop.  So you never perceive the lights as being off.

Since you want to have two noticeable delays, add a second delay:

```
while (raveMode) {
  SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 2);
  await Delay(300);
  SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 0);
  await Delay(300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (raveMode) {
  SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 2);
  await Delay(300);
  SetVehicleLights(playerInfo.vehicle, 0);
  await Delay(300);
}
```